# Migrating MySQL data from Yes/No varchar to a bit field

Tags: mysql, migration

I'm setting up a query that will take data from table A and move it into table B

Table B contains fields that are different types, and I'm trying to determine how to migrate Yes/No varchars over as 1/0 bits

My general query is structured as below

```
INSERT INTO 
    table_b (bitValue) 
SELECT 
    YesNoVarcharValue
FROM table_a
```

How would I setup a condition on YesNoVarcharValue so that it correctly inserts into table b as a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my goal using the following setup:

```
INSERT INTO 
    table_b (bitValue) 
SELECT 
    if(YesNoVarcharValue = 'Yes', 1, 0)
FROM table_a
```